# JSPDF doesn't render svg generated from D3 graphs completely in android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, svg, d3.js

I am working on a Hybrid mobile application using cordova supporting android and iOS.
I drew a line chart.As JSPDF doesn't support UTF-8 and I need to support Korean language, I have used addHTML plugin mentioned in here "http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/" and included html2canvas.
Every thing works fine in iOS. But in android the graph is not rendered completely. Only x and y axes are rendered but the actual line(plot) is missing.

```
var options = {
 pagesplit: true, format: 'png' 
};
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

 pdf.addHTML(d3.select('#linechart')[0][0],50,150,options,function(){var pdfOutput = pdf.output('datauristring');
var pdfOutput = pdf.output('blob');'
```

......code to save pdf using filesystem api `writer.write(pdfOutput)'})`